# AUTOINCREMENT en un columna NO PK

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, autoincremento

es sabido que una PK puede tener "AUTOINCREMENT", mi pregunta seria:
¿como haría para que un COLUMNA que NO es pk aumente de 1 en 1 como si fuese un autoincrement? lo haria con disparador o que?, Ayuda porfavor!!!

quisiera que la columna num_factura aumente automaticamente, GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086324/mysql-innodb-autoincrement-non-primary-key

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH .

Comment: si el numero de factura es autoincrement, entonces para que queres cod_venta?

Answer (score 1):

El atributo [`Auto_increment`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) es una característica del motor de base de datos que no está atada a la llave primaria, como tal se lo puedes poner a cualquier columna cuyo tipo sea un número entero, independientemente de que sea llave primaria o no.

Los requisitos para poder utilizar el atributo son:

- La columna tiene que ser parte de una llave, puedes satisfacer este requisito creando un `constraint` `unique` que contenga la columna (no tiene que ser la única, es preferible que sea la primera, pero tampoco es requisito).
- Solo puede haber una columna con el atributo `auto_increment` en la tabla.

Puedes tener, por ejemplo, una tabla como esta:

```
CREATE TABLE prueba (
    Id mediumint not null primary key
  , Numero bigint not null AUTO_INCREMENT
  , dato varchar(30)
  , constraint uqNumero unique (Numero)
);

insert into prueba (id, dato) 
values (1000, 'mil')
     , (2000, 'dosmil');
```

Lo que dejaría en la tabla:

```
Id      Numero  dato
-----------------------
1000    1       mil
2000    2       dosmil
```